# Selecting values within a range of date value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

From the following table I need to fetch data that falls within the range **01-07-2013 and 05-07-2013**

```
1138M0323   01-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0321   02-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0321   03-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0328   04-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0323   05-07-2013  3   1   P   P   P   P   P   P
1138M0321   08-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0321   09-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0321   10-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
1138M0321   11-07-2013  3   1   A   A   A   A   A   A
```

I tried out the following query but it shows an error like **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

`query = "SELECT * FROM student_attendance_table WHERE date BETWEEN '01-" & month & "-" & cyear & "' AND '05-" & month & "-" & cyear & "'"`

Values for **month and cyear** are fetched from the user

The Date field is of type DATE

I am using vb.net and sql server database

Comment: Instead of day-month-year, try the year-month-day date format, like `2013-08-03`.

Comment: @Dineshbabu: You shouldn't concatenate strings (sql injections). Instead, you should use parameters.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean point noted..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convert function in query.

See.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx